# GraphQL - Clojure - resolver-fn

Tags: clojure, graphql

I am researching how to use graphql in clojure and it all seems to make sense, and I can follow the Demo Project, except for the `resolver-fn`

In https://github.com/tendant/graphql-clj the resolver function is defined to be

```
(defn resolver-fn [type-name field-name]
      (cond
        (and (= "QueryRoot" type-name) (= "user" field-name)) (fn [context parent args]
                                                                {:name "test user name"
                                                                 :age 30})))
```

And in the demo, https://github.com/tendant/graphql-clj-starter, the resolver function is

```
(defn starter-resolver-fn [type-name field-name]
  (match/match
   [type-name field-name]
   ["Query" "hero"] (fn [context parent args]
                      (get-hero (:episode args)))
   ["Query" "human"] (fn [context parent args]
                       (get-human (str (get args "id"))))
   ["Query" "droid"] (fn [context parent args]
                       (get-droid (str (get args "id"))))
   ["Query" "objectList"] (fn [context parent args]
                            (repeat 3 {:id (java.util.UUID/randomUUID)}))
   ;; Hacky!!! Should use resolver for interface
   ["Human" "friends"] (fn [context parent args]
                         (get-friends parent))
   ["Droid" "friends"] (fn [context parent args]
                         (get-friends parent))
   ["Character" "friends"] (fn [context parent args]
                             (get-friends parent))
   ["Mutation" "createHuman"] (fn [context parent args]
                                (create-human args))
   :else nil))
```

I am confused about what arguments the `resolver-fn` should take.

I see that it returns another function but where do the `context`, `parent` and `args` come from for this function.

Any help would be much appreciated